# Maintaining a git branch starting from a certain commit.

Tags: git

I think the answer to this is scattered somewhere in the docs and in other questions here, but I couldn't find something that related exactly to my situation, so I am posting this. Please feel free to point me to any relevant answers elsewhere.

I have three branches: `wip`, `deploy-dev`, `client`.

- `wip` is the working branch internally for our team. It includes 3rd party keys/secrets and some local environment config.
- `deploy-dev` is also internal, but it has different config to test a deployed version.
- `client` is the branch that gets pushed to the client's remote. It removes 3rd party keys/secrets that we use for testing.

#### The problem

My `wip` branch has lots of commits. For the first release to the client, I would like to squash them into a single commit. So I did this:

- `git checkout -b client`
- `git reset --soft <first commit>`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "v1.0 release to client"`

After this first commit in the `client` branch, I would like to checkout `wip` again and continue working on v1.1. Then I should be able to checkout `deploy-dev` and `client` respectively and merge `wip` into them.

But when I checkout `client` and `git merge wip`, I am getting the entire commit history back into `client`.

I'm missing something easy, but I don't know how to describe it without describing the whole situation. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to learn the magic of `git rebase`. See, for example, [When would one need git-rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922933/when-would-one-need-git-rebase) and [git rebase vs git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge) to start with.

After you squash `client`, you should have something like this.

```
  A--B--C--D[wip]
 /
X--E--F--G[deploy-dev]
 \ 
  Z[client]
```

Run

```
git checkout wip
git rebase client
```

and also, presumably,

```
git checkout deploy-dev
git rebase client
```

Now your DAG will look like this:

```
  A--B--C--D
 /
X--E--F--G
 \ 
  Z[client]--E'--F'--G'[deploy-dev]
   \
    A'--B'--C'--D'[wip]
```

Of course, you will need to resolve any conflicts, just as if you'd done a `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a gigantic pain.  You **cannot** merge anything with `client` any more; the history is completely different as far as git is concerned.  You effectively have two unrelated projects that happen to live in the same repository and produce the same files.

You'll have to juggle resets, or use rebasing in creative ways.  With reset (I think!):

```
git checkout wip
git reset --soft client
git add .
git commit...
```

`git reset --soft` will change the branch git *thinks* you're on, without changing any of your files.  So you'll have the files in `wip` and git will think you're on the `client` branch, and then you can just mass-commit it all again.

You could also use rebase:

```
git rebase --onto client X wip
```

where `X` is the last commit on `wip` that has already been squashed into `client`.  This will take all the new commits and recreate them, one at a time, on top of `client`.  You can also use `-i` to get interactive mode, which will let you squash them together or rewrite the commit messages as you go.

You'll have to do this for every release, and you'll get some even wackier results if you make a mistake.  Ideally, you should either:

1. Write your commit history from the start so it can be made public at any time—keep secrets out of band, etc.  Bit late for this now, though.  Or:
2. Use some other mechanism to deliver code to your client, like [tagging](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html) the commit and then just emailing them a tarball.  If they want to track diffs, you can generate one with `git diff v1.0..v1.1`, or they can do it themselves.