# Calculate cpu through linux commands

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I would like to know the cpu uage and i tried to get through the 'top' commands.

But seems used CPU above it shows "19 %"  while in the process list it shows for 100% for cpu.
So please let me know how to get the exact value for CPU usage.

top - 05:14:39 up 34 days, 14:57,  1 user,  load average: 0.20, 0.31, 0.30
Tasks: 231 total,   2 running, 184 sleeping,   1 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): **19.0 us,**  2.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 78.4 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16123248 total,  3329216 free,  7078736 used,  5715296 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1048572 total,   743164 free,   305408 used.  9380980 avail Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
27928 root      20   0  415656  10196   5212 R **100.0**  0.1   0:00.17 runc:[2:INIT]
27933 karthik+  20   0   33992   3496   2956 R   6.2  0.0   0:00.01 top

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPzIF.png)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does [How to get overall CPU usage on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922933) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cpu usage shown in top and ps are not showing exactly the same statistics.

The 'top' command by default shows the summary of cpu usage across all cores. If you press '1' in 'top', you will see the usage for each core.

The output of 'ps' shows the total cpu usage time divided by process run time. Having 100 may mean that your process used single core 100% during run time. On 4-cores cpu, the top will probably calculate around 25% total cpu usage.

The 'man' page for both commands may provide some additional details as well.

Comment: Thank much @mnikolic for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

`top` only shows total CPU usage, that's different from which you see in details, try other cmds show more detail information.

on Linux: try `mpstat -P ALL 1` cmd, show CPU load per core.
on Mac: try `install htop`