# recovering from git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have a local branch work, where I created two new files a.py, b.py and committed them.

Then, instead of doing "git rebase origin/master", I accidently typed "git rebase origin master", and now the commit I did is gone and the files are gone. Does anyone know how I can recover my files?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase)

Git keeps the old refs (until you clean them up).  You can switch back to the old refs from before the rebase just fine.