# git rebase abort and empty reflog

Tags: git, git-rebase, reflog

I stupidly aborted a forgotten rebase with commits and uncommitted changes both on top of it, so it blew everything away, similar to questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693640/aborted-old-git-rebase-and-lost-commits-since-the-rebase-started).

I know about the reflog and immediately went to look in there, however it contained only a single hash of a non-useful pre-rebase state. What is going on? How can I lose reflog entries?

EDIT: in response to @kan below, here's roughly what I did:

```
git checkout badbranch
git rebase master
# CONFLICT, realized branch was bad and not needed anymore, but did not rebase --abort!
git branch -D badbranch
git checkout goodbranch
# some commits and edits here
git commit -av
# notices "you are currently rebasing" in the commit message
git rebase --abort # DOH
git reflog
```

The reflog only contains `a8f06a6 HEAD@{2}: rebase: updating HEAD` now

Comment: `git fsck` was of no help :(

Comment: Description quite vague, could you show us history of commands you done?

Comment: Did you `git log` anytime during the rebase? This will sometimes save me.  Look back through your terminal buffer for any commit id(s) from the rebase. Create tags for each of them so that `git log` will show them to you (and any commits that came before them). Then look at the full git log and (hopefully) find your missing commits.  Than rebase or cherry-pick the missing commits back into master.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the commit ids in the scrollback. I am starting to suspect that the actual commit objects are somehow lost as well, too.

Comment: What about the reflog for `goodbranch`? (although there should be reflog entries for `HEAD` too, so this is puzzling)

Comment: The reflogs for all involved branches are like this. It seems like something caused them to spuriously expire?

Answer (score 0):

This should be clearer with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022):

See [commit 9a1925b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a1925b08f3d9b71f06226f5ac32f24587f39151), [commit 6159e7a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6159e7add493cf1d62b4817eb86ac8890e768c17), [commit be0d29d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be0d29d301ffe284b123247d6680b289f73924a4), [commit 33f2b61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33f2b61ff9039247fd26d8b40db7e87e16ffe214), [commit 1f2d5dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f2d5dc4d2bbcae87736fcd7b7c0e6542008c5f7), [commit da1d633](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da1d63363f13d4d65c59564c74fd8dd598b39c49), [commit 4e5e1b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e5e1b4b616f0354218ff2e2ff3c71e4c730bbe1), [commit 57a1498](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57a1498592986c7532a37dd7f3eb96dc72d75878) (12 Oct 2022) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
See [commit a524c62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a524c627a424171c9cc2be2258725adc3f0bcc5a) (17 Oct 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit 8851c4b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8851c4b0652f7e69abfe0016503ab9ea1d247c84), 30 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`rebase --abort`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6159e7add493cf1d62b4817eb86ac8890e768c17): improve reflog message
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> When aborting a rebase the reflog message looks like
>
> ```
> rebase (abort): updating HEAD
> ```
>
> which is not very informative.
> Improve the message by mentioning the branch that we are returning to as we do at the end of a successful rebase so it looks like.
>
> ```
> rebase (abort): returning to refs/heads/topic
> ```
>
> If `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION` is set in the environment **we no longer omit "`(abort)`" from the reflog message**.
> We don't omit "(start)" and "(finish)" when starting and finishing a rebase in that case so we shouldn't omit "(abort)".

So `git reflog` should be of better help in your case, starting with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

---

Also, still with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), avoid setting `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION` to improve readability of the sequencer internals.

See [commit 0e34efb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e34efb31d89a143e42788f26f07e2bf8776a851), [commit d188a60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d188a60d7228f051bb4004924d20d961ada636f3) (09 Nov 2022) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ff84d03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff84d031a9d819da99707010e289a46eb8f661f3), 23 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e34efb31d89a143e42788f26f07e2bf8776a851): stop exporting `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Now that struct `replay_opts` has a `reflog_action` member we no longer need to export `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION` when starting a rebase.
> If the user has set `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION` then we use it when initializing `reflog_action`.