# I git aborted rebase and lost all my work

Tags: git

I aborted rebase and lost all the work, I had not commited anything else that what I can recover from the repo. That is, I made a commit yesterday and pushed to a branch, kept on working until today without commiting any new work, and aborted the rebase.

I tried `git reflog` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693668/380830) and there is  `HEAD@{0}: rebase: updating HEAD`
and there are `HEAD@{1}: ... HEAD@{7}:`

Since I hadn't commited any work, did I loose it permanently? Also, the branch in which I was switched when aborting rebase

Is there a way to got to right before the abort rebase?

Thank you

Comment: I was under the impression that you can't rebase if you have unstaged changes.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do a `git stash`? Try `git stash list`. If you see something that resembles WIP try `git stash pop` or `git stash apply`.

Comment: What OS are you using? What version of Git? What does `git rebase.autostash` return?

Comment: @astrochun I am in Android Studio and clicked a button that said abort rebase, I have no idea what it did. Now I also see that it switch me to a different branch

Comment: "I made a commit yesterday and pushed to a branch" then you can recover that commit.

Comment: @matt yes, I worked from yesterday until today, I want to recover the work from yesterday until today, that is what the question is about

Comment: @VonC I am in linux mint. The command returns git: 'rebase.autostash' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: @user3808307 I meant `git config rebase.autostash`

Comment: I wouldn't count on it. Git saves commits. That is all it saves. Only commits can be recovered. I do not know what you were rebasing or why but I would assume that whatever is not committed is lost.

Comment: @user3808307 On Linux Mint, check if Timeshift is active (https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/timeshift)

Comment: @VonC it doesn't return anything. I also have now (cause I've been messing around trying to fix this)  HEAD@{2}: rebase: updating HEAD So I reset hard to HEAD@{2} but it didn't work

Comment: If by any chance you _added_ those files that you had been worked on at a point in time, they are dangling objects in the DB. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560184/recover-dangling-blobs-in-git

Comment: @user3808307 I always activate `rebase.autostash` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114760/6309), that way I don't loose any work in progress in case of rebase. If not, any file not added to the index, and not committed... would be gone.

Comment: @VonC: rebase without autostash should refuse to start if there is uncommitted work. (Emphasis, perhaps, on "should" here? )

Comment: @torek I suspect rebase can start if the files are new ones, not involved in the rebased files. But aborting a rebase seems to involve a clean of the working tree. Not sure though, since I have always worked with `rebase.autostash true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize:

- A [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) starts with resetting the current branch is to `<upstream>`, or `<newbase>` if the `--onto` option was supplied. This has the exact same effect as `git reset --hard <upstream>` (or `<newbase>`).
  `ORIG_HEAD` is set to point at the tip of the branch before the reset.
- any private file would therefore be gone, which is why [`git config --global rebase.autostash true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114760/6309) should always be set.
- any file added to the index (but not committed), might still [be present in Git internal database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9560184/6309).
- Linux Mint might have saved something [in TimeShift](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/timeshift)
- If not, don't forget to check the [JetBrain Android Studio local history.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html): you might be able to [restore deleted files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/local-history.html#restore-files-from-local-history) (this is for PyCharm, but might also apply to android Studio).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The local history has been the saver this time