# Reverting an interactive git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

After completing a feature branch, during a `git rebase -i` I accidentally removed all my commits. I'm not completely sure but I suspect that instead of squashing my commits, I replaced the entire entry with a commit message.

http://shafiulazam.com/gitbook/4_interactive_rebasing.html says:

> The last useful thing that interactive
>   rebase can do is drop commits for you.
>   If instead of choosing 'pick',
>   'squash' or 'edit' for the commit
>   line, you simply remove the line, it
>   will remove the commit from the
>   history.

My question is: is there a way to revert/undo this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you have just done the rebase, you can try as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git/964927#964927):

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

as [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski) [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git/967611#967611):

> `ORIG_HEAD` is previous state of `HEAD`, set by commands that have possibly dangerous behavior, to be easy to revert them.
>   It is less useful now that Git has reflog: `HEAD@{1}` is roughly equivalent to `ORIG_HEAD` (`HEAD@{1}` is always last value of `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD` is last value of `HEAD` before dangerous operation).

If you have executed some operations *since* the rebase, the [**reflog** can still help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase/135614#135614).

Answer (score 17):

You can do "git reflog" and get back your old HEAD.