# Interactively cherry-picking commits with rebase

Tags: git

I can't seem to figure this Git scenario out after reading the man page and searching some of the questions here, so I hope some of you can help me out.

Here's the situation. I've got two branches, let's call them `master` and `experimental`, with the commit graph looking like this:

```
A---B---C---D  master
     \
      E---F---G---H  experimental
```

and I want to end up here:

```
A---B---C---D---F---H  master
     \
      E---F---G---H  experimental
```

I could achieve this by successively cherry-picking all relevant commits from `experimental`, but I'd like to use `git rebase -i` to get a list of all commits and select the relevant ones. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems like the cherry pick would be easier as it doesn't require any temp branches.  Keep in mind that you can specify ranges in the cherry pick command. In  your case, `git cherry-pick <sha of F>..experimental` would cherry pick G and H

Comment: Yeah, for ranges cherry-pick would be okay, but it's quite inconvenient to list all commits manually, especially if there are quite a few and they are not successive. And I like being able to `git rebase --abort` if things go awry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but first, mark your `experimental` branch with a new '`tmp`' branch:

```
git checkout experimental
git checkout -b tmp
```

Then do your rebase:

```
git rebase -i master
```

And drop all the commits you don't want.

```
         (master)
            |
A---B---C---D---F'---H'  tmp
     \
      E---F---G---H  experimental
```

Finally, merge `master` to `tmp`

```
git checkout -B master # reset master to tmp
git branch -d tmp
```

---

Since a rebase moves a branch, and since it is `master` that has to change, [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827378/interactively-cherry-picking-commits-with-rebase/24827423#comment38548453_24827423) the shortest solution:

```
git checkout -B master experimental
git rebase -i master@{1}
```

See more on `HEAD@{1}` at:

- "[Reverting an interactive git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5375113/6309)" and
- "[HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309)"

Comment: Yup.  I'd just `git checkout -B master` rather than the heckout/merge, because we're resetting the branch label, why bother with the two-step and worktree churning.

Comment: Thanks! I'd tried lots of combinations, and almost got there, but didn't think to create a temporary branch. This works excellently.

Comment: @Mark yes, since a rebase moves the branch, and since you want to keep 'experimental' in place... a tmp branch was mandatory.

Comment: For maximum concision, `git checkout -b master experimental; git rebase -i master@{1}`...

Comment: @jthill good point, and I have added it to the answer, but let's not be *too* concise here: it is useful to understand what takes place behind the scene, in order to get why your shorter version works.