# git crash during rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have rather big amount of file in repository. Thus git sometimes crashes due to out of memory exception during rebasing changes.

E.g.

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
(nasty out of memory exception)
.....
```

So once I got that exception, I tried again rebasing

```
git rebase master
```

And it told me that branch `feature` is up to date. That seems strange, as rebase finished with exception.

Are there any way to avoid oom exception? May be somehow tell git use smaller amount of memory. Could this exception be cause of repository corruption? If it causes corruption are there any way safely roll back changes made during rebase to state that was before `git rebase master` was called?

Comment: What did the exception say?  Might be important.

Comment: I can't reproduce it now. But it is like following: `blablabla out of memory, blablabla, malloc failed (could not allocate 100500 bytes)`

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
git repack -a -f -d
```

http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/running-out-of-memory-when-doing-a-clone-of-a-large-repository-td1491051.html

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running this on a VM or are storing some large files. Filter branch out large files if you can or bump up the memory :/

Not much else I can add unless I have more info..

Comment: What about repository corruption?

Comment: What do you mean saying `large files`? Does git need to store all files from repository in ram to rebase changes?

Comment: Not sure. But it may be trying to. How big is the biggest file you have in history?

Comment: Total working copy is about 2.2 gb. The biggest file is about 12 mb.

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase $BASE` starts by doing `git reset --hard $BASE`

If it crashes due to out of memory after that, it means you're left with your branch pointer pointing to `$BASE` instead of the commit it pointed to before.

That's why you're being told that `feature` is up to date when you `git rebase master` again, because `feature` is already pointing to the same commit as `master` after the out of memory crash.

To reset your branch back to the original commit you were on before, run

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`.
```

Or if you've done other work on the branch after the crash, run `git reflog` to find the original commit.

See also [Undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase)

---

After you got your branch back to the original commit, you can try

```
git rebase -m master
```

which will try a different rebase strategy that probably uses less memory if you have large binary files.