# "fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref" during interactive git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

Got 3 commits - one proper, and then two silly cleanup ones, typos etc. So I want to squash them. Fire away:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Sounds simple, and it should work - I've tried it after running into a problem, in a brand new repo, and it works as expected. Editor shows 3 commits, pick the top, squash the other two, save and quit, done. If I run in verbose mode, I see more details - git enters the detached HEAD state by checking out the 1st commit I 'picked', then does 'Rebasing 2/3' and 'Rebasing 3/3', apparently creating some temp commits along the way -- and then a success message; editor pops up again at some point, offering me to change the commit message. All's good.

But same command dies in a work repo! 3 commits in an editor, pick-squash-squash.. but this time, I don't see 'Rebasing 2/3', instead the very first line after 'HEAD is now at my-SHA-1', it runs into a fatal!

```
HEAD is now at 48a6c3d... <commit message>
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

But why *would* git expect HEAD to be a symbolic ref? Rebase process does detach HEAD - same as I see in my exploratory example - so why then the fatal in this second example, but not in the first one? cat .git/HEAD give me the SHA1 of the commit I've 'picked'...

I've spend several hours reading and researching, but something's just not right here, and I can't find what it is! I suspect that *maybe* some hooks are responsible (know little about them, and know the problematic repo does have some). Thank you for your consideration in answering this!

Comment: If you think that the hooks might be a problem, did you try turning off the hooks? They're located under `.git/hooks/`, just rename them to `<hook>.off`. There one pre-rebase hook in particular, `pre-rebase.sample`.

Comment: thanks for suggestion - hooks are now somewhat demystified.. it didn't have any effect on the problem, but at least that killed a red herring )

Comment: "symbolic ref" in Git has nothing to do with symbolic links on a filesystem: "the ref" in the Git parlance is an entity pointing to a commit -- a branch or a tag; this is short for "reference". A ref might point directly to the SHA-1 name of a commit (and it's then direct) or to *another* ref, and then it's "symbolic". For instance, `HEAD` typically points to something like `refs/heads/master`, not to the master's tip commit.

Comment: thanks @kostix , I didn't even notice how I misquoted git, using 'symbolic link' in place of 'symbolic ref'. So, when in detached HEAD due to 'git checkout some_commit_SHA1', cat .git/HEAD prints exactly that SHA1; if I checkout a branch, it prints something like `ref: refs/heads/master'. So my understanding is, the latter IS a symbolic REF -- but is the SHA-1 of a commit a symbolic REF? It's a REF alright -- looks like, to quote you, it's a 'direct' REF. If so, then it clears up some confusion -- but doesn't explain what causes the fatal in one case, but not in other...

Comment: ran this: `$ git symbolic-ref 48a6c3d62b81d94ac79c3f039bfe9b924b6744f0`
got this `fatal: ref 48a6c3d62b81d94ac79c3f039bfe9b924b6744f0 is not a symbolic ref`.  So ok, the SHA-1 of a commit indeed is not a symbolic ref. Looks like that's the reason for the fatal - but that still doesn't explain why the dummy example, which looks the same, works.

Answer (score 6):

Your "work" repo is probably broken somehow. See [I can't git rebase --interactive anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488655/i-cant-git-rebase-interactive-anymore) for details.

I'd try running `git status` in your work repo to figure out what is going on. Then e.g. `git rebase --abort`, `git merge --abort` or something like that may be required.

I'd run `git fsck`, too.

After your repo and working directory is good to go, interactive rebase should work fine. Also note that you may need `git rebase --root --preserve-merges ...` in case you want to touch the first commit in the repo.

Answer (score 3):

there is also a possibility that `git commit` was executed instead of `git rebase --skip` or `git rebase --continue`

this might have added the unwanted commit.

You may run `git reset HEAD~1` and then execute `git rebase --continue` to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while trying to push a tag while on detached head.

```
@❯ git push origin 1.1.1
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
error: failed to push some refs to '<repo>'
```

Detached head since the main branch was one commit ahead of the commit with the tag.

I was allowed to push the tag by temporarily resetting the main branch to commit that the tag was on:

```
@❯ git checkout develop
@❯ git reset --hard @~
@❯ git push origin 1.1.1
@❯ git reset --hard origin/develop
```