# Rebase succeeds, but displays "fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref"

Tags: git, rebase

I read [I can't git rebase --interactive anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488655/i-cant-git-rebase-interactive-anymore) and other comments on the web.  My repository seems just fine, I am on a branch, `git log` seems to match my expectations, ditto `git status`.  I sometimes do an interactive rebase to get my work in progress commit to the head after merges, or to combine commits into better history.  But it seems like I commonly start getting messages like this, followed by a success message.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)

$ git status
On branch feat/WEB-8790-httpd-accounts-ui
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feat/WEB-8790-httpd-accounts-ui'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git rebase -i 5adb675. # in editor reorder 1 commit
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feat/WEB-8790-httpd-accounts-ui.
```

Nothing *seems* amiss, the commit history shows the rebased commits as rewritten (lg is an alias I use for log that formats more compressed listing)

```
$ git lg -5 
8470687 - 2023-06-30 (11 minutes ago) Marvin Greenberg: [WEB-8790] Initial work, wip
45d65a0 - 2023-07-20 (11 minutes ago) Marvin Greenberg: [WEB-8878] Fix typo
2725e07 - 2023-07-20 (11 minutes ago) Marvin Greenberg: [WEB-8878] standardize make targets
e2551f8 - 2023-07-17 (11 minutes ago) Marvin Greenberg: [WEB-8861] Add test script
5adb675 - 2023-07-18 (7 days ago) dev1: WEB-8607 merge from develop to get fixes.
```

Can someone explain the detached head fatal errors, and explain why the rebase is successful?  Is there something I can do to fix this repository, although again it is not obviously broken?

Comment: Related / similar: ["fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref" during interactive git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18104923/11082165)

Comment: Yeah @Brian61354270 I saw that too, but it also seems to suggest that rebase is failing and there are visible problems.  Mine seems to succeed.  But good to have the ref here too.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is operator error.  I had looked at the ANSWERS on ["fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref" during interactive git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18104923/11082165), but after @brian61354270's comment, I reread all the comments on the question - and I'm sure the problem is in my hook scripts that I use to modify the commit comments.

That also explains why the rebase succeeds, because the error in the hook script doesn't cause the hook script to fail.  So I have two things to fix.