# Git rebase: override subset of local conflicting commits with upstream code

Tags: git, rebase

We forked an opensource project and developed features on top in a particular branch. Now I am trying to rebase our code with the new upstream branch. However, the rebase gives many conflict error messages. I wish to override a subset of conflicts with the incoming commits but I could not find how to do that.

The following command would override all conflicts with upstream code:

```
git rebase -Xours upstream/branch
```

But I only want to override those commits related to documentation (not those related to code) .

Any way to achieve this ?

Comment: There is no easy way to *automate* this. Depending on the code base, the simplest method might be to run the rebase without any `-X` flags, and when conflicts occur, inspect them by hand and use `git checkout -m --ours` on those documentation files where you want to take their file wholesale. Note that `--ours` is different from `-X ours` as it will drop unconflicted changes as well. You can get the effect of `-X ours` using `git merge-file`, but it is substantially trickier than just running one `git checkout`.

Comment: @torek Will `git rebase --skip` achieve what I want ? I do not understand what --skip does. It will skip the local commit and accept upstream ? Or will just retain the local changes and discard upstream commit ?

Comment: What `--skip` does is to skip the patch / cherry-pick item. Remember, rebase works by *copying* (some subset of) the original commits to new, different, presumably-better commits. If one of the commits that rebase was attempting to copy now was one of your original commits that you no longer wanted (e.g., was documentation changes), you could use `git rebase --skip` to skip it and move on to the next one to copy. If a subsequent commit depends on the one you just skipped, though, you'll continue to get more conflicts. If that next one is also documentation-only, you could skip it as well.

Comment: The main danger here is that you could `--skip` a commit that has *both* documentation changes (that you want to omit) *and* other changes (that you want to apply) by mistake. In all cases, though, you can *hand apply* just those changes that you *do* want, back out any changes that you *don't* want, mark everything resolved, and `git rebase --continue` to move on to the next-commit-to-be-copied. This is usually pretty slow and painful and is one reason rebasing is not always the right choice.

Comment: When `--skip` skips a patch, this patch is one coming from community or the one I committed in local ? Eg. there was conflict in `.gitreview` file and if I do `--skip` it just accepts the incoming community change, which is exactly what I want. So in my case, if I am careful that only the doc changes are being reported in a conflict, `--skip` will accept the incoming community changes ?

Comment: @torek BTW I tried your suggestion of `git checkout -m --ours` but it fails with error `# git checkout -m --ours
fatal: '--ours/--theirs' cannot be used with switching branches` If I try with specific file name
`# git checkout -m --ours .gitreview
fatal: git checkout: --ours/--theirs, --force and --merge are incompatible when checking out of the index.` If I drop the `-m` flag it proceeds but again stalls at `# git add .gitreview
# git rebase --continue
Applying: Update .gitreview for stable/mitaka
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
....`

Comment: Oop, I'm not sure why I said `-m --ours`: I meant `--ours` during the resolving merge conflicts phase of a rebase. (It must be used for all the file(s) in question, as you did here with `.gitreview`, though you can give it more than one file name at a time, or even a directory name if all doc files are in `doc/` for instance.) When you hit that "No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?" stage, you may have finished resolving a commit that you can `--skip`, but as usual you have to figure that out manually: Git doesn't know what's documentation (=> can be skipped) and what's not.

Comment: @torek I hit "No changes ..." right after I do `git checkout -m .gitreview`. It asks me to `--skip` and that is what the confusion was to begin with. What will skip do and when to use it. Git documentation says that there would be very rare cases when it would be needed, but doesn't give an example of when.

Comment: I could, I suppose, answer this now as a question of the form "when does `--skip` make sense". Note that I have no idea what you are putting in `.gitreview` (though it looks like this file is part of [gerrit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review)).

Comment: Say I have forked out branch named `foo`. The `.gitreview` points to this at present. Rebasing it with upstream branch `bar`, the incoming `.gitreview` points to bar which is reported as conflict. If I `--skip` this, then upstream `bar` is accepted. So would that be the case with every `--skip` ?

Comment: Ah, I see: the contents of `.gitreview` include a branch name. You are choosing to resolve the conflict by choosing their branch name.  Let's turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is an answer to a somewhat modified question (see the long comment thread).  Here's the modified question:

> We have some branch *B* we made in a local repository, based on an upstream repository and its branch *upstream/U*, which used to identify commit `1234567`.
>
> The upstream repository has been updated by its owner, and now `upstream/U` identifies commit `89abcde`.  There are many commits and many changes between `1234567` and `89abcde`.
>
> We have chosen to rebase our branch `B`, which has a long list of commits, so that all of our commits will be applied after `89abcde`.  That is, we now have:
>
> ```
>   ...--o--1234567--o--o--...--o--89abcde   <-- upstream/U
>                \
>                 B1--B2--B3--...--B1000   <-- B
> ```
>
> but will, in the end, have:
>
> ```
>                 B1--B2--B3--...--B1000   [abandoned]
>                /
>   ...--o--1234567--o--o--...--o--89abcde   <-- upstream/U
>                                     \
>                                      B1'-B2'-B3'-...--B1000'  <-- B
> ```
>
> Therefore, we started this operation by doing:
>
> ```
> git checkout B
> git rebase upstream/U
> ```
>
> Along the way, though, we hit a lot of cases where, while copying commit `B1` to `B1`, `B2` to `B2`, and so on, we get a conflict.
>
> Resolving these conflicts sometimes means "take the upstream version of the file".  This is true for all the documentation files, for instance.  It's also true for some cases where the only file conflicting is named `.gitreview`.
>
> If we run `git checkout --ours .gitreview` to take their version of the file, and attempt to continue like this, Git says:
>
> ```
> # git checkout --ours `.gitreview`
> # git add .gitreview
> # git rebase --continue
> Applying: Update .gitreview for stable/mitaka
> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
> #
> ```
>
> What does this mean and how should we proceed?

Now, as shown in the illustration within the question, what `git rebase` is doing is *copying* each commit, `B1`, `B2`, ..., `B1000`, for every commit that is on branch `B` that is not on branch `upstream/U`.  To copy a commit, Git essentially runs either `git cherry-pick` (some variants of `git rebase` use this) or `git format-patch` followed by `git am`.

Either one turns each commit into a diff (a *changeset*, in Version Control System terms) that can then be applied to some other commit.  When using `git cherry-pick` this changeset will be applied through Git's three-way merge machinery, with the merge base being the parent of the cherry-picked commit.  The two branch tip commits are the current commit, which is the left side or "local" or `--ours` commit that I call *L*, and the commit being cherry-picked as the right side or "remote" or `--theirs` commit that I call *R*.

Note that these changesets are applied one at a time, after which Git makes a new commit.  Git starts by checking out commit `89abcde`, using what Git calls its "detached HEAD" mode, so that commit `89abcde` is what is in the index and work-tree and there is no current branch at all.  Git will then cherry-pick commit `B1`.  Since the *current* commit is `89abcde`, we will refer to the upstream code as `--ours` or the *local* or *L* version.  Since the commit being applied now is `B1`, we will refer to our own code from branch `B` as `--theirs` or the *remote* or *R* version.

Assuming the changeset from `B1` is successfully applied to `89abcde`, Git makes a new commit, using the log message from commit `B1`.  This new commit is now `B1'`, and our detached HEAD now points to this new `B1'`:

```
                B1--B2--B3--...--B1000   <-- B
               /
  ...--o--1234567--o--o--...--o--89abcde   <-- upstream/U
                                    \
                                     B1'  <-- HEAD (detached)
```

The process now repeats with `B2`, and repeats over and over again for as many commits as there are to copy (1000, in this example), until we are exhausted and thoroughly sick of Git. :-)

When using `git am`, the change-set is applied slightly differently, but usually the result is the same.  The key difference is that Git *doesn't* immediately resort to the three-way merge; instead, it first attempts to apply the diff directly, to the file named in the `git format-patch` output.  If the diff fails to apply, *then* Git extracts a merge-base version of the file to which the diff failed to apply.  The diff will apply correctly to the merge-base version, producing the *R* version of the file.  (The *L* version is simply the one in the existing work-tree.)

As with `git cherry-pick`, the *merge base* version is whatever version of that file is stored in the *parent* commit of the commit we're copying right now.  So when falling back, Git diffs the merge base version against the HEAD version.

Let's look now at what happens with `.gitreview`.  Suppose we're copying commit `B11`.  The file `.gitreview` contains the name of a branch `foo` in commit `B11`, but it contains a different branch name `bar` in the commit we made as `B10'`.  Git has, in diffing `B11` against `B10`, identified `.gitreview` as changed, so it's in the changeset.  In fact, it's the *only* file in the changeset: `B11` consists entirely of a change to `.gitreview`.

We now choose not to take our change, so we run:<sup>1</sup>

```
# git checkout --ours .gitreview
# git add .gitreview
# git rebase --continue
```

and get the complaint.

The reason we get this complaint is that this modified `.gitreview` file was the *only* change.  By using `git checkout --ours .gitreview` to extract the version of `.gitreview` that goes with commit `B10'`, rather than the version that goes with `B11`, we've made the current index-and-work-tree match commit `B10'` exactly.

Git notices that there's nothing changed in the index and work-tree as compared with `HEAD` (which is `B10'`), and complains.

The solution at this point is to run:

```
# git rebase --skip
```

which tells Git, in effect, *we no longer want commit B11 after all: just drop it from the list of commits to copy.*

Git will go on to commit `B12`.  This may have a change to `.gitreview`, or it may not.  If it doesn't, we won't see any problem there.

If `B12` *does* have a change to `.gitreview`, we may get a conflict, or we may not, depending on:

1. Are we doing `git am` or `git cherry-pick`?
2. If we're doing `git am`, did the patch apply cleanly, or not?
3. If we're doing a three-way merge because of `git cherry-pick`, or because the patch didn't apply cleanly in (2), is there a *merge conflict*, or not?

Assuming `B12` copies without conflict, we'll now have:

```
                B1--B2--B3--...--B1000   <-- B
               /
  ...--o--1234567--o--o--...--o--89abcde   <-- upstream/U
                                    \
                                     B1'-...--B10'-B12'  <-- HEAD (detached)
```

Note how `B11` is simply skipped.  Git will proceed with copying `B13`, and so on.

Remember, in all cases, all Git is doing is a line-by-line application of diffs.  It has no idea what these diffs *mean*.  It just knows that they can be applied, or cannot; or that they conflict with each other (when combining two diffs via three-way merge), or do not.

You can get one merge conflict per file, per commit.  So if there are 1000 commits to copy, and 1000 files in each commit, you *could* have up to 1 million merge conflicts.  Chances are that most commits change at most a few files, though, and most changes apply cleanly or have no merge conflicts; so it's pretty likely that there will be at most a few conflicts per merge, for at most a few thousand of these to resolve.

Nonetheless, you may want to use some strategy other than copying all 1000 (or however many) commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>These `#` prompts concern me slightly: they suggest you're doing all this as user `root`.  The usual sh/bash prompt is or ends with `$` for non-root users.  It's generally wisest to "live" as much as possible as someone other than root.