# What exactly does `git rebase --skip` skip during a rebase?

Tags: git

When you perform a rebase, git asks for manual intervention if it can't resolve differences between your current branch and the new base branch.

If you resolve conflicts and type `git rebase --continue`, git treats the resolved code as the 'new code' for that commit.

But what happens when you hit `git rebase --skip`? It can't leave the code as it is—there are conflicts—so it must be doing something more than just 'skipping'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If there is a conflict, `git rebase --skip` simply skips the entire commit. The changes from that commit will not be in the history after the rebase finishes successfully. Let's look at an example

```
A-B-C <- master
 \
  D-E <- foo
```

Now say D causes a conflict after

```
git checkout foo
git rebase master
```

Then `git rebase --skip` results in

```
A-B-C <- master
     \
      E' <- foo
```

where E' contains the same textual changes as E.

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice. I'm still not 100% clear: say I add some code in D and leave it unchanged in E. Will the code I added in D still exist in E after the rebase?

Comment: @adc17 no the changes do not exist in E to begin with. They will not be in the new branch after the rebase finishes.

Comment: @adc17 Note that each commit is an incremental set of changes since the previous commit. The local copies of all files are the accumulation of all of the commits for the current branch (or HEAD if you do not have a branch checked out). Since E does not contain the changes of D, E' will not either.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what was blocking me. So it sounds like `git rebase --skip` is more of a `git rebase --delete-commit-and-continue`.

Comment: @adc17 The commit `D` in my example is **not** deleted. It still exists in the repository but has been orphaned because it is not in the history of any branch. Likewise the original commit E exists as well. It helps if you understand that each commit not only contains the changes to your code as I described earlier, but also a reference to its parents. Two commits which contain the same textual changes but different parents are different commits. That is why I use the name E' after the rebase. This is a new commit which contains the same changes as E but has a different parent.

Comment: @adc17 "skip" is more apropos because as `git rebase` makes copies of each commit on the branch `foo`, we tell it to just skip copying D.

Comment: @adc17 If you are interested in learning Git in more depth, I highly recommend [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). This link is for a free online version. The first 3 chapters explain everything you need to know for day-to-day usage. Later chapters dig into more advanced topics.