# how to update my feature/release/hotfix/support branch with new content?

Tags: git

For example, I'm dealing with feature branch, another developer pushed just right now to origin/develop his latest fix, and I have to use (add) his fix in my feature branch.

how I should do it ?

```
git checkout -b my-feature-branch
... dealing with my issue ...
... alarm! another developer just released his fix, I need it here in my feature branch ...
git stash
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git rebase my-feature-branch develop
git checkout my-feature-branch
git merge develop
git stash apply
... dealing with my issue ...
git commit
git checkout develop
git merge my-feature-develop
git push origin develop
```

Is it correct behaviour ?

In that case very hard to figure out where my branch was started and where were finished.
And second point I'm doing `rebase` for public branch (develop) and it's not good, right ?

What the proper way to update (refresh) working branch with new info ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems wrong: `git rebase my-feature-branch develop`

It should be:

```
git rebase develop my-feature-branch`
```

What you need to do is rebase what you already done in `my-feature-branch` on top of the now updated `develop` branch.
No need to `merge` develop in `my-feature-branch`.

The full sequence would then looks like

```
git checkout -b my-feature-branch
... dealing with my issue ...
... alarm! another developer just released his fix, I need it here in my feature branch ...
git stash
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop

# remember that such a rebase will starts with a
# git checkout my-feature-branch
git rebase develop my-feature-branch
git stash apply
... dealing with my issue ...
git commit
git checkout develop
git merge my-feature-develop
git push origin develop
```

Comment: Could you please clarify these two lines ?

# remember that such a rebase will starts with a
# git checkout my-feature-branch

Comment: @user1016265 from [`git rebase` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase): `git rebase [<upstream>] [<branch>]`: If `<branch>` is specified, `git rebase` will perform an automatic `git checkout <branch>` before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch. In your case, no need to checkout `my-feature-branch` after having rebased it on top of `develop`: the rebase will have first checked out `my-feature-branch`, so at the end of the rebase, your current branch will be `my-feature-branch`.

Comment: thanks for explanation. What if I did like I described in the beginning, should I fix something ? or everything will be ok ?

Comment: @user1016265 the beginning is fine until the rebase: you shouldn't rebase develop on top of `my-feature-branch`. Did you already do that?

Comment: @user1016265 then you can force develop branch back to where it where with the reflog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase/135614#135614, and then resume with the right rebase.

Answer (score 0):

Find the commit(s) of the hotfix, then [`cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) it/them.