# How do I revert `git fetch upstream; git merge upstream/master`?

Tags: git, revert

This question is different from other questions in that, I want to keep some commits while I revert some commits.

Here 's my setup.

```
Upstream repo on github (public repo which I don't own)
Personal repo on my server(git clone --bare $upstream)
```

My workflow was like this:

```
Need to customize my personal branch
   1. check out origin/master(Personal)
   2. make changes
   3. push to origin/master

Need to get new feature or bug fix from the original author(github)
   1. git fetch upstream
   2. git merge upstream/master
```

Now I find upstream/master has a bug and want to revert,
How do I go back to the state before I fetch/merged upstream for the last time?

Edit.

Suppose

> 1. I merged upstream
> 2. I merged what a team member pushed to origin/master(Personal)

Now I want to undo the step 1.

> git reset --hard commit_sha_of_one_prior_the_merge_1
>
> (Although finding the sha is not easy. git log shows a lot of commit
>   sha's of upstream, so it's not easy to find
>   commit-sha-of_one_prior_the_merge_1 which is not of `upstream` but of
>   `origin/master`)

How do I keep the step 2 merge?

Suppose a slightly more complex scenario

> 1. I merged upstream
> 2. I merged what another team member pushed to Personal
> 3. I also pushed my work to Personal

Now I want to undo the upstream merge.
How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge

Answer (score 3):

Since you have an actual merge commit--because you've been introducing your own changes--you should be able to do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Assuming your last commit was the merge commit in question.

Comment: I have other commits in my private repo, other than the merge-commit

Answer (score -1):

You can reset your local `master` branch to the `origin/master` state (if you haven't push your merge to `origin/master`) with :

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

If that's not possible you can use the reflog :

```
git reflog
```

You can see [undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase) for more details

Comment: This is the opposite of what OP wanted.