# GIT Rebase Gone Wrong - Possible to Rewrite History to Fix

Tags: git

I've still got my GIT training wheels on and I recently had a bit of a stack. It's no big deal, but I think it presents an interesting problem to solve. If you take a quick look at the following pick, you can see that the commit where the FluentValidationTrial branch is pointing just kinda stops:

[image]

That happened when I was playing around with rebase -i.
The history should show no divergence i.e. commit d7d9b1e should follow d2044a6.

Does anyone know how I can clean that up? Should be interesting. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `develop` is already a rebased version of `FluentValidationTrial`, starting from `a6afd1b`.

Check if the two commits tagged `Further work on the validation ...` have the same content :

```
git diff 08dd217 d2044a6
```

then you can probably drop `FluentValidationTrial` :

```
git branch -d FluentValidationTrial
# After that, if you want to a branch named FluentValidationTrial
# pointing at 08dd217 :
git branch FluentValidationTrial 08dd217
```

Comment: Ah I see. That branch's history in already in the develop branch. I'll go ahead with that suggestion.

Comment: The diff showed they were the same. I think that has cleaned it up. Only comment is that I had to use a capital D flag to force the deletion. Not sure why as there was nothing to commit. Not in staging or unstaged. But clean history now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While you have the branch `develop` checked out, simply do a rebase -i on top of `FluentValidationTrial`:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase -i FluentValidationTrial
```

Then drop any duplicate entries in the commits.

---

The other alternative is to go to [git reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), and restore a rebased branch on its past SHA1.
(As in "[undoig a rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135614/6309)")

But do use Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), as before that, "`git rebase -i`" did not leave the reflog entries correctly.

See [commit 1f6965f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f6965f994f8fe2fca80e17b5dbb293d05716be9) (07 Apr 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3aa30cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3aa30ccb1c242bf328892e3d7ba218411aadbc6a), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f6965f994f8fe2fca80e17b5dbb293d05716be9): honor `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
>
> There is a lot of code to honor `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION` throughout Git, including some in [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f6965f994f8fe2fca80e17b5dbb293d05716be9/sequencer.c); unfortunately, `reflog_message()` and its callers ignored it.
>
> Instruct `reflog_message()` to check the existing environment variable, and use it when present as an override to `action_name()`.
>
> Also restructure `pick_commits()` to only temporarily modify `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION` for a short duration and then restore the old value, so that when we do this setting within a loop we do not keep adding " `(pick)`" substrings and end up with a reflog message of the form
>
> ```
> rebase (pick) (pick) (pick) (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
> ```

Comment: Not sure what to do in VIM here. I just accepted the stuff that appeared on running the rebase and all it did was move the HEAD pointer to d2044a6. I think I need to reset HEAD. I can be cavalier with what I try as I have backed up the whole repository.

Comment: @onefootswill what did you see in VIM? You should be able to replace the 'pick' by 'drop' on the lines you don't want, and generally to reorder commits.

Comment: I'm going to blow away that repo and grab a copy from backup because that last opn completely ruined it. It now thinks there's a branch called develop|REBASE-i

Comment: [This](http://i167.photobucket.com/albums/u122/sixesallround/wronger_zpsf0ff6116.png) is what I see

Comment: @onefootswill: git has detected that some commits on `develop` introduce the same changeset as commits already present in `FluentValidationTrial`. If such is the case, he has already removed the duplicates : you only see the 5 commits starting from `Further work on the validation ...`