# Git, Git Extensions Lost Files

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am just beginning to work with Git, Git Extensisons and have encountered a problem. I have deleted files locally then commit and perform a rebase. Then using Git Extensions Push option select FORCE and REPLACE TRACKING REFERENCE options Push the changes.

The problem is these files appear to be permanently removed beyond recovery with all reference to them and the commit that removed them also not available.

This is potentially a serious problem.

Any help or information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `git reflog` may help you get back the commit that you can then checkout. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undoing a git rebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase)

Answer (score 3):

Try `Repository > Git Maintenance > Recovery lost objects..` to recovery old commits before your changes