# push rejection after a git rebase

Tags: git

I'm working on the the feature branch called `auth`, which was branched out from `master` branch:

```
C1 (master)
 \ 
  C2-C3 (auth)
```

After I've made `C3` commit, I pushed the `auth` branch to remote for backup. Then `master` branch is updated on remote and the history looks like this:

```
C1-C4 (master)
 \ 
  C2-C3 (auth)
```

I'm rebasing `auth` branch to updated `master` branch and the history now looks like this:

```
C1-C4 (master)
    \
     C2-C3 (auth)
```

Then I make more changes on `auth` branch, make `C5` commit and push `auth` branch to remote and the **push is rejected** with the message that there are updates on remote that I don't have locally. But I know that no one else pushed to the `auth` branch on remote. So why is this behavior?

This [article](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/getting-solid-at-git-rebase-vs-merge-4fa1a48c53aa) provides just a simple explanation for such behavior:

> Beware though: if the rebased branch had been pushed to a remote (for backup
>   purposes, for instance), you’ll need to force the next push of it with
>   the -f option, as you just replaced its commit history with a fresh
>   one.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rebase [has changed the history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) of the `auth` branch.

That is why you need a forced push, which is OK only if you are the only one to work on this branch.
If not, it would be best to:

- [reset `auth` branch to its state before the rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134882/6309)
- merge `master` into it
- add `C5`
- do a normal push

As in:

```
C1-----C4      (master)
 \      \
  C2-C3--M--C5 (auth)
```

Comment: Thanks, VonC! I think to better understand your answer I'd need to know how git knows that there changes on remote that are not here, i.e. why git reports exactly this error. What's the topic to investigate or resource to read about that?

Comment: @Maximus it is not really "changes that are not there". It is simply because the auth SHA1s on GitHub differ from the auth SHA1 you are trying to push (as illustrated in http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html#rebase)

Comment: @Maximus `git rebase` changes the commits SHA1 by changing it's parent commit; this makes git consider the local commits to be different from the remote one.