# Recover commit list after undoing an interactive rebase in git?

Tags: git, rebase, undo, git-interactive-rebase, git-squash

My situation: There are two remotes, `origin` and `fork` (the latter is owned by me). I checked out `origin/devel`, changed some code and committed like 5x to my local branch `test`. I pushed my commits to `fork/test`.

Then I started an interactive rebase, while on my local `test` branch:

```
git rebase -i --onto origin/devel
```

Git opened an editor with a list of my 5 commits, ready to pick, squash or whatever.

I accidentally closed the editor instead of deleting everything or Ctrl+C and `git rebase --abort` in git console. Thus, it started the rebase.

In order to undo it, I used `git reflog` and `git reset --hard HEAD@{...}` and also `git checkout fork/test -B test` later, since my remote should also contain the pre-rebase state. All of them seem to recover the state, but if I start the rebase again, there will be no commit in list (only a `noop` entry).

How do I recover the original state before the rebasing, so that the original commit list is shown again?

[Undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase) does not cover this issue. I'm mainly interested in why this happens and how to really revert the rebase, not how to alter the `rebase` command to get the commit list again (as I said, `git reset` and `git checkout` did NOT undo it properly from my point of view).

The ultimate goal is to rebase my `test` branch onto the up-to-date `origin/devel` at some later point, squashing all my own commits since `test` diverged from `origin/devel`.

**//edit:** It looks as though Git forgot the fork-point. `git merge-base --fork-point origin/devel` does return the `origin/devel` commit before my own commits however, and `git rebase -i that-commit` gives me the initial commit list. So why does `--onto` not do the same anymore?

Comment: Why does the linked question not cover the issue? Move your branch's HEAD back to where it was before and then you can start over from square one.

Comment: It was at my latest (5th) commit before rebasing, and so is it after a reset to the latest commit of `fork/test` (I did not push after the rebase). Yet, rebasing it again with the identical command does not give the same commit list. Instead, I get a blank list, unless I explicitly specify the common ancestor commit. Why doesn't it find that ancestor implicitly anymore?

Comment: Try `git rerere forget` ?

Comment: @FractalSpace: How is that related? I did not have any merge conflicts.

Comment: Most tools resolve simple conflicts automatically. If you have any of such installed, such as kdiff3, meld, vimdiff, chances are they may be playing a role. Its just a guess, worth trying.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ on Windows (as editor, not merge tool obviously) and there was no merging and no conflicts when I ran the first rebase. If there are conflicts, TortoiseGitMerge or some similar msysgit merge tool is used. `git rerere forget` just gives an error that it's deprecated to call without path, and that it couldn't write the rerere record.

Comment: I noticed one difference between the states before and after the rebase: `git status` reported "Your branch is ahead of origin/devel by 5 commits", whereas it now reads "Your branch is up-to-date with fork/test". I shouldn't really matter however, because I explicitly specify `origin/devel` as new base. It kinda makes sense if no commit is listed if I'm ahead of `origin/devel` and not behind by a single commit, but why did it list my commits the first time then? `git rebase -i origin/devel` works, it doesn't with `--onto`, but it did initially.

Comment: I don't think you're resetting properly. The old commit is still in your repo. If you reset your branch back to that commit, you *will* be in the same spot you were in before the rebase. Git doesn't delete or rewrite history, so unless you've done a garbage collection or pruning, you should be able to do a complete restore.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of rebasing to alter history? :) By old commit, do you mean the rebase commit? I'm not sure if my last commit before the rebase appears before the rebase commit in reflog... Or should I explicitly reset to the hash of refs/remotes/fork/test (remote HEAD, which should be < rebase commit)?

Comment: @CoDEmanX: heh, good point. I'm referring to the commit that represents the HEAD of the branch you're on *before* you did the rebase; that is, the commit that you would have seen if you did `git rev-parse HEAD` before you started your disastrous rebase. If you can reset HEAD to that commit, it'll be as if you never rebased at all.

Comment: Well that would be the latest commit of my remote branch `fork/test`, because I pushed before the rebase. But it doesn't work. Or the same commit I got locally, to which I reverted to using reflog and reset/checkout HEAD@{#}. It didn't work. What's weird is that all hashes up to my last commit in reflog are identical... Shouldn't there be a change after rebase? Or is it irreversible? See here: http://pastebin.com/NkwXgD4v