# Can I get back deleted files after using git rebase?

Tags: git, github

Today I was going to upload my local project files to Github using shell, but unfortunately deleted the local files after calling "git rebase" command. How can I get the deleted files back?

Comment: maybe this link would help? Duplicate?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase

Comment: Unfortunately I did not make a copy of this version, so it's an emergency!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check `git reflog` for a revision history for your repo, something like:

```
b3f2a61 HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): Adding some more files
ba90657 HEAD@{1}: rebase: Message
3dcbd41 HEAD@{2}: commit: Adding some files
```

You can resore the repo to a previous state by using the commit ID in the first column like

```
git reset --hard <ID>
```

Be careful that this wipes everything that was committed to the repository after the restore point. You may want to back that up separately before doing a hard reset.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful!

Comment: This saved my day! Thank you!