# How to undo git reset --hard

Tags: git, reset

If I reset my last commit using `git reset --hard HEAD^`, how do I undo the reset?

I don't have anything more to ask, but apparently there are length requirements for this message. I'm just writing more here to pass the quality standards.

Comment: Hmmm...did you push the branch to the remote before doing this reset?  Either resurrect the previous branch from another version, or else get ready to sift through the reflog.

Comment: Yup, it's a duplicate. Didn't see that one before.

Comment: You should flag your flag this question as duplicated then

Answer (score 4):

All changes that are not committed are lost. If it was committed, you can try `git reflog` to restore it.

This is already asked many times, so please see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase) for reference.

Comment: His problem is because of an accidental `git reset --hard` not `git rebase`

Comment: reflog can be used, regardless of what kind of destructive operation

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi If he nuked his working directory without having committed or stashed, the work really might be lost.  Perhaps the IDE has a history feature in such a case.

Comment: I agree with you that the cure is the same, however the two questions are a bit different, `rebase` is not `reset --hard`. So your anwser is great to me except the part where you say `This is already asked many times`, a bit confusing I think