# Automatically rebase with a specific commit

Tags: git

Recently I rebased my local branch from a master branch, but I messed up. It seems that sometimes I accidentally staged the merge-conflict directly, and I ended up with a bunch of `<<<<` in my files.

Now it was relatively easy to fix those error in a new commit, which currently sits on top. But I don't want want it to be a new commit, I actually want to change all the commits.

Is it possible to apply those changes from the last commit, recursively to all commits, and if there is a conflict let git choose the change of the last commit?

Comment: Probably it will be easier to redo the rebase.

Comment: You can undo the rebase as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase