# Cancel git rebase if already pushed with force

Tags: git, gitlab, push, rebase

So I managed to perform a rebase and pushed the changes to Gitlab but now I am getting errors and would like to cancel the whole rebase and go back to where I started. I am working on a "feature-branch" and I did the rebase to "develop" branch.

What I did was:

- Git checkout feature-branch
- Git rebase develop
- Git push -f origin feature-branch

So now both my local branch and the remote branch contains the changes from the rebase. Is there anyway I could cancel the whole rebase and push -f and try to do it again? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the commit on the branch before the rebase happened, then reset it back - (git log or git reflog will help that). Also GitLab has a network tab which should allow you to see this easily.

example of git reflog as that one will probably be the easiest:

```
git reflog feature-branch
```

The above will give you some output like:

```
73d836b feature-branch@{0}: rebase finished: feature-branch onto e806e41f1fe22624e6546abd65c332c934214891
129e6d3 feature-branch@{1}: commit: Commit message
```

Get the commit ref from the above output (pick the point where the latest good commit was)

```
git reset --hard {commitRef}
git push -f // this will push your branch back to how it was before rebase
```

Answer (score 4):

you could check out git reflog
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

```
git reflog feature-branch
```

and then find the latest good commit and  then

```
git reset -- hard 129e6d3
```

where that number is the commit ref

EDIT:

after a google search, I found this, https://medium.com/@shreyaWhiz/how-to-undo-a-mistaken-git-rebase-life-saver-2977ff0a0602 which seems like your problem