# Can I undo deleting a commit in git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit

I intended to squash a commit but accidentally missed a step and deleted a commit - can I get it back

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Then on the line with the commit I wanted to squash I deleted the line
then I did `:wq`

Then my work disappeared

Can I get the commit back?

I have tried git reflog but I can't see the commit

Comment: You can use the reflog to restore the branch on the commit where it was before the rebase then run the rebase again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase)

Comment: In the reflog, you don't have to search for the commit you've accidentally removed, but for the previous tip of the branch (that still included the commit).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get it back by going back to a checkout of a commit with history that included the commit you've lost.

So use reflog to find the point your branch was at before the `rebase -i` and check out that revision, then check `git log` for the last few commits.