# Changes in first commit (without date changing)

Tags: git, gitlab

I wanted to add changes to the first commit in my repository.
I made the following commands:

```
git tag root `git rev-list HEAD | tail -1`
git checkout -b new-root root
// changes in code
git add .
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon Oct 1 22:36:58 2018 +0200"
git commit --amend --no-edit --date="Mon Oct 1 22:36:58 2018 +0200"
git checkout @{-1}
git rebase --onto new-root root --committer-date-is-author-date
git branch -d new-root
git tag -d root
git push origin master --force
```

Everything works, except that in the list of files (GitLab), those that have not been modified by any commit have Date update as new:

[image: screenshot from GitLab]

[image: screenshot from GitLab]

Can anyone tell me how to improve it? Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure your last parameter is not ignored, can you repeat your sequence with:

```
 git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date --onto new-root root 
 # instead of
 git rebase --onto new-root root --committer-date-is-author-date
```

You will need to restore the `root` branch first, using [`git reflog`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135614/6309) or [`git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692763/6309).

Then check first the author/committer dates of your root branch before and after rebase with:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:"%aD --- %cD" root
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your new first commit (`new-root`) was wrong. These commands set only the author date but not the committer date because the value of `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` is not propagated to into `git commit`.

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon Oct 1 22:36:58 2018 +0200"
git commit --amend --no-edit --date="Mon Oct 1 22:36:58 2018 +0200"
```

The simplest solution is to add a trailing `\` like this just before the newline:

```
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon Oct 1 22:36:58 2018 +0200" \
git commit --amend --no-edit --date="Mon Oct 1 22:36:58 2018 +0200"
```

Now `git commit` sees the variable.