# Git use old version of commit to rebase

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have two branchs in my project, feature and develop. I commit and push my edited code to my feature branch two times(commit1 and commit2, the second one is the latest version). The problem is when I want to rebase my develop branch with my feature branch, it use commit1 version to rebase. How to fix this problem?

Comment: It depends on the command you use to perform your rebasing operation, or the place you're currently at when you do. Please show us these commands.

Comment: `git checkout feature` and `git rebase develop feature`. However, I accidentally perform `git push -f` without resolving any conflicts. Then I notice that something went wrong, I try to rebase again and the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As in "[Undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135614/6309)", check the output of [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) and:

- reset `feature` to what it was before the rebase
- same for the `develop` branch

Then try again your rebase, paying attention to conflict resolution and rebase status.
Finally `push --force` one more time.