# Git - "Lost" Commits

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, gitlist

Coming from an SVN environment so Git is pretty foreign thus far.

```
me@www:/var/www/$ git --version
git version 2.17.1
```

It's just me on these servers and in this Git environment.  I cloned from another local server.  I've been writing code, committing and pushing.  I wanted to change the comment for the last pushed commit.  I read to use the following commands:

```
git commit --amend
```

I entered the new message and saved.  I then...

```
git push origin master --force
```

Now only my last, updated commit appears in Git.  I believe I read that all the previous information is still there - it's simply not displayed but at some point it will be garbage collected.  I've been looking through the various git shell tools and man pages but I'm not sure what to do without further screwing this up.  How can I restore the history?

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undoing a git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase)

Comment: Does this need to be done on the server that I cloned from or the server the clone is on?  Or does that even matter?

Comment: Your local checkout.