# Git help is broken

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I was in a terrible situation where I accidentally rebased on master. I typed `git help` and it was still broken. Can someone explain what the actual ___ git help does?

In my opinion it's not very helpful...

Comment: It opens the man page or a website for that command, depending how it is configured.

Comment: Also............lol.

Comment: The man page came up.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`git help`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-help), which is only for opening man pages, this kind of situation would be better "helped" with a source like [`ohshitgit.com`](https://ohshitgit.com/) or [`oh-shit-git-zine.pdf`](https://pub.wxcafe.net/oh-shit-git-zine.pdf), page 16 (if the rebase is still in progress).

Basically, you need to [undo your last rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135614/6309) (if it is already completed).