# How to change branch base in Git?

Tags: git, rebase

I have feature branch which was branched off of master. Let's call it feature1

There is another feature branch (let's call it feature2) created by another person.

I need to make my feature branch to be based on feature2.

What's the proper way to do this?

My understanding is that I have to:

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase --onto feature2 feature1
```

Is this correct?

And what about:

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase -i feature2
```

Which one is better? I mean, git rebase -i is interactive so at least I can see what commits will be included, so I guess that's safer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the checkout,

```
git rebase feature2
```

should work just as well. The '-i' option you proposed as an alternative allows you to select the commits you want to include. It's not "safer": just different.

Comment: OK thx. Can this operation be undone? Like can I revert somehow if anything goes wrong?

Comment: You can find what to do in case you want to undo the rebase here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/135614/11334020

Comment: Please, stop editing the question and, if you find it useful, please select my reply as an answer.