# How to get the new changes from another branch with git

Tags: git

I merged branch **B** to my branch **C** a week ago and did some updates on my branch C.

The same time, my colleague, did some updates on his branch **B**.

I want to get his updates on my branch **C**.

I am really confused, because he tells me to just **rebase** on his branch - but that keeps **deleting all my new updates** / added files.

I tried to **merge** the two branches again - but somehow **I don't get his updates this time**.

Our project looks kind of like this:

```
Origin---o---o---o---o---o---      main
 \
  o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o B
   \               \(merged)       \(rebase here?)
    o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o---o C
```

Comment: Your colleague is right: if neither him nor you rewrote history, a rebase is sufficient and will do the job. In other cases, we should have more infos in order to provide an answer.

Comment: How do you do the rebase or merge ? Did you commit before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebasing is complicated, and was probably a bad idea in this situation. Let's adopt your topology:

```
o---o---o---o---C1---o---o---o---o friend
 \               \
  o---o---o---o---M---o---o---o me
```

To pick up your friend's changes, the right and simplest thing to do was (on `me`):

```
git merge friend
```

That would give this:

```
o---o---o---o---C1---o---o---o---o friend
 \               \                \
  o---o---o---o---M---o---o---o---M2 me
```

You cannot coherently rebase at this point, despite what your friend said, because `me` already includes a merge commit (M) from `friend`. Rebasing can't easily cope with that; it will ignore the merge commit, and thus the effect of the merge will be undone in your branch. There are ways around this, but it's not worth going into them here.

The key question now, however, is how to get out of the mess you've gotten yourself into with a bad rebase followed by a bad merge. The answer is to use the *reflog*, which makes much of what you do in Git undoable. When you say `git reflog` you will be shown a list of all previous states of your HEAD. One of these will be the state *just before you started the rebase*. You want to go back to that by saying `git reset --hard <SHA>` (as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71750947/341994)). Now do the merge that you should have done, and move on.