# Undo git pull --rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-reset, git-revert

Sorry for bothering everyone! Please help.

I wrongly used the `git rebase --hard` and overwrite all local files. Then I use `git reflog` and `git reset --hard` but did not find the former version! I searched for many [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase) but it seems that they only deal with `git rebase` without `--hard`.

How could I find the deleted files! Thanks!

---

I checked again and found that I used `git pull --rebase`. Sorry for misunderstanding.

---

Command sequences:
`git stash`  -> `git pull --rebase`  -> `git reset --hard with id` (failed) -> `git stash apply` (succeed)

Comment: `git rebase` does not have an option `--hard`, that's why you haven't found any questions mentioning it. For git **reset** --hard, there are plenty: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22git+reset+--hard%22+recover

Comment: `git rebase` doesn't have option `--hard`. Did you mean `git reset --hard`?

Comment: @IMSoP Sorry, I found that I used `git pull --rebase`

Comment: @phd sorry I found that I used `git pull --rebase`

Comment: `git pull` wouldn't pull if there're uncommitted changes in the working dir so you most probably stashed them. Just unstash them back with `git stash pop`,

Comment: Please can you [edit] the question to show the exact sequence of commands you ran. Don't worry about showing which parts you've edited, anyone curious can see [previous revisions of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75081926/revisions), just make it as clear as you can for somebody reading the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did not use stash to take snapshots before the `reset --hard`, there is unfortunately nothing you can do to restore your lost working tree.

Comment: I did use `stash` before `git rebase`. Anything that I could do?

Comment: @standerQiu If you use stash, you can now use it to recover your working tree changes as well. `git stash apply`