# Merging unrebased branch to rebased branch

Tags: git

I have a feature branch in my local and remote. I did a rebase of that branch on to master. Next I pushed it to remote. Now I found that the conflicts were not resolved properly during the rebase. So I undid the rebase using the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/135614/3172290

Now if I push the this "de-rebased" feature branch to remote, how will the merge process happen? Will the remote reflect exactly as my local? I am wary of experimenting this without knowing consequences as many people are working on that branch.

Comment: "as many people are working on that branch"? Then you should not rebase the branch in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope below steps can help 

- Take your master branch update

- create a new branch form master  

- checkout to that new branch

- rebase your local branch on top of this new branch

- test your project functionality at new branch

- checkout to master branch and take an update

- merge your new branch in to master

- Test your project  functionality at master branch

- Push your master branch once you have with test
```